# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in a tabularx table

Tags: tables, tabularx, badness

I'm encountering the `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` error when using the below provided code. By testing the code, I've noticed that the error vanishes when reducing the first column to a single word per cell. However, I require more than one word in the first column cells. Can you explain the root cause of this issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXXX}
        \hline
        Dataset (Year)      & Image size & Bands & Class Number\\ 
        \hline
        Indian Pines (1992) & 145 × 145  & 200   & 16\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}             
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is not error. It is a warning that bad line break are happened. In your case, it is the cell "Indian Pines (1992)" cause the warning. You could set content length depended column specifier for the first column. Such as `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXXX}`.

Comment: Thank you, @Tom. Given that I have numerous rows in this table, resulting in multiple `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` warnings, could you provide strategies for resolving this issue? Are there any LaTeX packages that can prevent this warning from recurring?

Comment: IMHO, you could ignore them if you don't mind the format doesn't looks prefect. It is the feature to tell that if the output will potentially looks ugly. If you really set it off you could set `\hbadness=10000` in the preamble or inside the table env.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might add `\raggedright` for the first column (and `\centering` for the other three), but you leave plenty of empty space.

I don't think that equal width columns add to clarity for the table, so I propose other two realizations: one where the table is spread to the text width, the final one where the table is set at its natural width.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright}X
  >{\centering}X
  >{\centering}X
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
}
\toprule
Dataset (Year)      & Image size & Bands & Class Number \\
\midrule
Indian Pines (1992) & 145 × 145  & 200   & 16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{This is with \texttt{tabularx}}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  c
  c
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
Dataset (Year)      & Image size & Bands & Class Number \\
\midrule
Indian Pines (1992) & 145 × 145  & 200   & 16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{This is with \texttt{tabular*}}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp!]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  c
  c
  c
  @{}
}
\toprule
Dataset (Year)      & Image size & Bands & Class Number \\
\midrule
Indian Pines (1992) & 145 × 145  & 200   & 16 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{This is at its natural width}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Take your pick. I recommend the last one.

[image]